# firebase throwing this typeError: getfirebase is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

Getting around firebase authentication but it keeps on throwing the following `TypeError` message and breaks the app:

> TypeError: getfirebase is not a function

Please take a look at my store and authReducer if I'm doing it wrong.
In my store, I have provided reduxfirestore with getfirestore and also getfirebase to react-redux-firebase. I'm using v2 of react-redux-firebase.

** store.js

```
import rrfConfig from "../config/rrfConfig";
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
import firebaseConfig from "../config/fbConfig";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.firestore();

const initialState = {};

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig),
    reduxFirestore(firebase)
  )
);

export default store;
```

**authActions.js

```
export const signInAction = credentials => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getfirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getfirebase();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS" });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_ERROR", err });
      });
  };
};
```

**authReducer

```
const initialState = {
  authError: null
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_ERROR":
      console.log("login error");
      return {
        ...state,
        authError: "login failed"
      };
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      console.log("login success");
      return {
        ...state,
        authError: null
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

**rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";
import projectReducer from "./projectReducer";
import { firestoreReducer } from "redux-firestore";
import { firebaseReducer } from "react-redux-firebase";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  project: projectReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer,
  firebase: firebaseReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ghandhi-land",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^6.0.4",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^2.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.8.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

**SignIn component

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { signInAction } from "../../store/actions/authActions";
class SignIn extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: " "
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.signIn(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Sign In</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    signIn: credentials => dispatch(signInAction(credentials))
  };
};

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SignIn);
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. Could you `console.log` the value of  `getFirebase` in *store.js*? Also, where are you exactly getting the `TypeError` error? Is it when you are executing the `signInAction` method?

Comment: when i console.log getfirebase, this what it saying ```ƒ getFirebase() {
  if (!firebaseInstance) {
    throw new Error('Firebase instance does not yet exist. Check your compose function.');
  }

  return firebaseInstance;
}```

Comment: and yes it throws this typeError when executing the signInAction

Comment: @mgarcia. why is the getfirebase undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are composing the redux middlewares you are applying the thunk middleware with this statement:

```
applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore }))
```

The names of the methods you are passing as an extra argument are in camelcase notation: `getFirebase` and `getFirestore`.

However, when you are trying to retrieve the extra argument in *authActions.js* you are destructuring it as `getfirebase`:

```
return (dispatch, getState, { getfirebase })
```

You should destructure your object with the same notation (in camelcase). So, your code should be:

```
return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase })
```

Comment: it worked. thank you very much. i have being on this for 2 days now